# Horizontal bar chart in Android with different x positions of entries or values

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart

I need to use a library which use this, I tried with numAndroidCharts by numetriclabz (ColumnRange and HorizontalRangeBarStacked) but it has many errors.

I have to do something like a graph of activity selection problem, and I don't know if other android libraries have the posibility of change the x position of the values of the chart.

Comment: search on https://android-arsenal.com/

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/40?sort=created

Comment: I have not found anything similar in android arsenal.

Answer (score 0):

Use this library..

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

horizondal barChart also there is.

and use it. like this.

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart
                    android:id="@+id/recect_activity_performance_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                     />
```